# forcing a download using PHP / jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, download

I know there are already many questions about forcing a download with PHP, but  I can't find what I'm doing wrong and what should I do.

I'm having an list with filenames, and I want to download one of them by clicking a button.

My jQuery:

```
$(".MappeDownload").on("click",function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            fileId=$(this).val()
            $.post("ajax/DownloadFile.php",{ id : fileId})
})
```

and on the server side I have a table with the file names and the file path.

```
$sql = "SELECT vUploadPfad, vUploadOriginname  FROM tabUpload WHERE zUploadId='$_POST[id]'";
$result =  mysql_query($sql) or die("");
$file = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$localfile = $file["vUploadPfad"];
$name=$file["vUploadOriginname"];
$fp = fopen($localfile, 'rb');
        header("Cache-Control: ");   
        header("Pragma: ");         
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($localfile));
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='".$name."';");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
        fpassthru($fp);
        exit;
```

The AJAX request is successful, I'm getting the right header(filesize, filename etc...) but the download are not starting.

Comment: try hard coding a filename instead of $name, i had previous issues with this and it may be the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need ajax, just redirect to the address that forces the download. The page will not change so, instead of `$.post("ajax/DownloadFile.php",{ id : fileId})` you should have `location.href = "ajax/DownloadFile.php?id="+fileId` and, in your PHP file, convert your $_POST to $_GET

Answer (score 1):

The response to an AJAX request will never trigger a download. AJAX requests are silently handled in the background, they never trigger visible activity directly.

You need to redirect the main page or an iframe to trigger the download.

Answer (score 0):

1. Return file name in ajax
2. Do `window.location.href = 'returned file name'` and download will start!

Answer (score 0):

There is my solution:

```
<script>
//downloading the file

 $(document).on('click', '.download_file', function(){
  var path = $(this).data("name");
  var action = "download_file"

    $.ajax({
        url: "action.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {path:path, action:action},
        success: function(data)
        {
            window.location.href = path;
        }
      })
})
</script>
```

And the **action.php**

```
<button  type"button" name="download" data-name="'.$name.'" class="download_file btn btn-success btn-xs">Pobierz</button></td>'
```